# Configuration management with different database and websites

Tags: 8, database, configuration, installation-profiles, entities

We have a central code base (Git repo). From this code base we deployed several websites already.

- Till now we used features. The websites which are already in production they have a filled database with a lot of content.
- From now we switch over to drupal 8 Configuration management.

In the central code base we have set `$config_directories[CONFIG_SYNC_DIRECTORY] = 'config/base';`. This directory contains all the configuration, from where we deploy our new added configuration, after a `drush cex -y`.

But after I do:

1. *first* a new install off the site with [Configuration installer module](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_installer) and import all the existing configuration, everything works fine. I can import and export configuration without problems
2. but then I have to copy the production database (from the site which is already in production) back into this database. After that I am not able to import configuration anymore.

But I need to copy this database back in, because we need all the content from the existing site (which was based on Features)

I get an error the UUID is not matching etc... Is it possible what I want? And how do I get it working?

(I tried already manually copy/paste the correct `uuid:` in `system.site.yml`, but it still didn't work).

**Update:**
I use docker for my local Drupal 8 environment

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to make sure both sites share the same UUID.

Do you have drush? If so:

In the shell of your old site (copying from) get the UUID

```
drush cget system.site uuid
```

(You'll get something like 'system.site:uuid': bfb11978-d1a3-4eda-91fb-45decf134e25 - copy the value)

Then in the shell of your new site (copying to) set the UUID

```
drush cset system.site uuid <your_uuid>
```

EG: `drush cset system.site uuid bfb11978-d1a3-4eda-91fb-45decf134e25`

Then if you get an error something like "placeholder ... These entities need to be deleted before importing." run this command:

```
drush ev '\Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage("shortcut_set")->load("default")->delete();'
```

After all that, `drush cim sync -y` should allow you to sync the settings between your environments.

[Source](https://www.dannyenglander.com/blog/drupal-8-development-how-import-existing-site-configuration-new-site)

Comment: Thanks. yes indeed I get "placeholder ..." errors afterwards. But the whole thing is I need those entities (Content types etc). Let's say like you suggest to delete those entities, how do I get them back again?

Comment: do you have any idea or suggestion?

Comment: @100pic Many thanks! Very helpful, I was stuck with this for a while.

Answer (score 0):

An easy approach you can do is the uuid of the site will be available in `config/sync/system.site.yml` file. So in your terminal you can use cat (Linux) or type (Windows) to get the uuid displayed in terminal.

```
cat config/sync/system.site.yml | grep uuid
```

Then,

```
// using console
drupal config:override "system.site" uuid "<new-uuid>"
// OR, using drush 
drush config-set "system.site" uuid "<new-uuid>"
```

If you get the shortcut set place holder error

```
// using console
drupal entity:delete shortcut_set default
// OR, using drush 
drush ev '\Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage("shortcut_set")->load("default")->delete();'
```

Then,
`drush cim` **OR** `drupal ci`